# Limit of JQuery's append()

Tags: jquery

My database contains huge records. I wants to use twitter like pagination with the help of JQuery's append().

Is any limit available for JQuery's append()?

Comment: I don't really see the relation between paging and `.append()`. Can you elaborate a little more on how do you intend to perform this paging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a small chance you need to worry about maximum append limits (see Nick's answer). Speed is a larger concern.

I once asked a question about speed of adding elements and eventually tested it myself. [**See this topic for speed tests**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319472/should-you-add-html-to-the-dom-using-innerhtml-or-by-creating-new-elements-one-by). As you can see, `.innerHTML` is much faster than `.append()`.

Answer (score 2):

There's one limit which isn't really of concern here, [if the string's over 512 bytes then the dom fragments created by it aren't cached](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L398), but it seems you're more concerned with an upper-bound of content in general.

In that case, it's really whatever the limit of  `.innerHTML` in the browser is (pretty damn high), though when appending *lots* of content you may get some extreme lag in older browsers especially.