# how to append data when use ajax?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, ajax

I want to add modal when button click with ajax request

```
public static string CreateCompanyPartial(string path)
{
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        string url = path + "/CompanyProfils/CompanyCreateModalPartial";
        string content = client.DownloadString(url);
        return content;
    }
}
```

---

This is my request

```
$.ajax({
    type: "Get",
    data: {
        path: common
    },
    url: commonapi + "/api/CompanyProfilsApi/CreateCompanyPartial/",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data)
        $('#companyModal').append(data)
    }
})
```

---

I'm  trying append page, request is okay and getting data but not append all of them. Have a limit append function? Please for help.

> [image]

Comment: What's html look like? Have you tried doing `$('#companyModal').html(data)`

Comment: Yes exist .image is $('#companyModal')'s html

Comment: @acaputo yes i tried but same result

Comment: I added in body @Taplar

Comment: I intentionally asked if you verified it **logically**.  Verifying that an element exists logically is performing a `console.log($(selector).length)` in the logic immediately before you try to use an element.  If it prints out 0, it's not being found.

Comment: i tried and prints 1

Comment: Alright, so it's finding the element.  And I may have read your question wrong.  Are you saying it appending but not appending all the data?

Comment: append function is working but problem is not append all . Page have 1500 line but it append only 283 line .

Comment: And the data is showing the 1500 lines returned?

Comment: yes data showing 1500 line

Comment: Dumb question, but after the data can you confirm that modal doesn't have any hidden classes?

Comment: Then I might suggest you look at the results at around the 283 line point.  You may have some invalid html being generated that is fubaring it.

Comment: I've never liked passing HTML via AJAX. I much prefer passing JSON objects and then building the HTML in javascript.

Comment: and i try sent data with viewbag then it is working .problem after the page loads call

Comment: And I tried $('#companyModal').load(url,data) but same result.

Comment: Silly question, how large is your response from the server (the returned markup)? Possible answer here if > 512 bytes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794835/limit-of-jquerys-append

Comment: Yes it is worked get all data but this time scripts not work:(

Comment: have you tried copying the data from the console and pasting it into an [html validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input)?

Comment: I found problem.Problem is script files before loaded to ajax data . If ı can do reload script file after ajax request it will be .